# Redimensionar imagem e remover bordas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Estou fazendo uma "UI" com Canvas, onde apenas a parte central é redimensionada e depois reencaixada com as bordas. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém conforme o tamanho aumenta o "smooth" das bordas também, e eu queria saber como removê-lo.

Imagem base:

[image: Base]

Resultado final:

[image: Resultado]

Trecho onde qual a imagem é redimensionada e reencaixada:

```
left, top, bottom, right = 32;
width, height = 96;
h = 700;
w = 100;
con.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, left, top, 0, 0, left, top);
con.drawImage(bg, left, 0, width - left - right, top, left, 0, w - left - right, top);
con.drawImage(bg, width - right, 0, right, top, w - right, 0, right, top);
con.drawImage(bg, 0, top, left, height - top - bottom, 0, top, left, h - top - bottom);
con.drawImage(bg, left, top, width - left - right, height - top - bottom, left, top, w - left - right, h - top - bottom);
con.drawImage(bg, width - right, top, right, height - top - bottom, w - right, top, right, h - top - bottom);
con.drawImage(bg, 0, height - bottom, left, bottom, 0, h - bottom, left, bottom);
con.drawImage(bg, left, height - bottom, width - left - right, bottom, left, h - bottom, w - left - right, bottom);
con.drawImage(bg, width - right, height - bottom, right, bottom, w - right, h - bottom, right, bottom);
```

Encontrei como resolver, tem que colocar o código abaixo detnro do carregamento da imagem:

```
con.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
con.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
con.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
con.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: É assim, ele divide a imagem em 9 partes, e depois as partes 2, 4, 5, 6 e 8 são redimensionadas e reencaixadas, fazendo com que as bordas continuem intactas. E eu preciso que seja em canvas.